# Decode JSON Object in php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I sending a JSON object from my android app to my web service. (using volley). Here is a part of my code.

```
private void sendtoDB(final String ngno){

    String tag_string_req = "req_save_to_db";

    final JSONObject JSONdates = new JSONObject();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < dates.size() ; i++){

        try{
            JSONdates.put("date", dates.get(i));

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_UpdateDates, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) { ....}


        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("ngno", ngno);
            params.put("JSON", JSONdates.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

dates array contains several date Strings that i want to store in my Database. Below is the output of my JSON object (JSONdates).

{"dates":["Wed Mar 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016","Thu Mar 31 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016"]}

My question is how do i receive this JSON object in my php and how to decode it properly and get each date value to a variable so i can execute sql query accordingly.

This is my php code.

```
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

if(isset($_POST['ngno']) && isset($_POST['JSON']) ){

     $ngno = $_POST['ngno'];
     $json = json_decode($_POST['JSON'], true);


     foreach($json){
         $date = $json['date'];
         $job = $db->updateDates($ngno, $date);

         if($job){
              $response["error"] = FALSE;
              echo json_encode($response);
         }

         else{
             $response["error"] = TRUE;
             $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in Updating!";
             echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }

}

else{
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Dates are missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);     
}
?>
```

updateDates function

```
public function updateDates($ngno, $date){

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO datepicker(ngno, date) VALUES($ngno, $date)");
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

I get a syntax error near forearch($json) unexcepted ')'.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT 1:

changed the foreach loop in php code as following

```
foreach($dates as $date){
    error_log[$date];
    $job = $db->updateDates($ngno, $date);

    if($job){
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    else{
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in Updating!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

But now it says,  PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
Any help Guys? Im new to programming and not sure how to get it fixed.

Comment: Check php foreach syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

change `foreach($json){` to `foreach($json['dates'] as $date){`and delete the line `$date = $json['date'];`. See [php manual about foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for more info about the foreach syntax

Comment: Changed the code but now its give the following error, PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()